# How to Iterate over files in resources?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have several files in my `qrc`. They can be accessed by `QFile`, though `QDir` can't iterate over files in `qrc`. How can I get a list of items in a specific path in resources?

What doesn't work:

```
qDebug() << QDir(":/ui/images/").entryList();
// Prints an empty list
```

Comment: `QDir::entryList` should work fine for Qt resources. Are you sure that you use a proper path? If you can access resource files by `QFile`, then you can create a corresponding `QFileInfo` object and use `QFileInfo::absolutePath` to create a proper `QDir` object.

Comment: If the linked answer doesn't solve your problem, then you should probably check your prefix&path in the qrc file. If your qrc file is part of a library then you might have to use [Q_INIT_RESOURCE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Q_INIT_RESOURCE)